# Gradient Layer background

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cagradientlayer

I am trying to create a gradient background. i have followed steps on different tutorials but cannot get my background view to appear, I just get a white background.
I cannot understand what I am doing wrong or not doing. Code is below.
Help greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

extension CAGradientLayer {

    func backgroundGradient() -> CAGradientLayer {

        self.colors = [UIColor.green,UIColor.blue]
        self.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        self.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        self.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        return self
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer().backgroundGradient()

        gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
        print(gradient.frame)
        print(gradient.startPoint)
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient layers take `CGColor` instead of `UIColor`. Easy fix...

In your extension, change the `self.colors` line to:

```
self.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
```